# yeoman - generator-angular -> watch bootstrap 3.1.1 scss changes

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

hy

I've just installed yeoman and generator-angular.
everything works like expected, but changes in bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/* won't be caught in grunt watch or grunt serve tasks.
it's my first contact with bower and yeoman and I hope that this can be solved easily.

bootstrap.scss (imports all bootstrap scss files) is included in app/styles/main.scss witch will be converted to main.css in grunt watch task.

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple - just add this files to watch task in Gruntfile.js.

But **it is entirely bad idea** - you should not edit files under `bower_components` directory.

This files should be managed using bower, they are not even tracked by git and should not be(by default bower_components are in gitingore for this generator).

If you need to override something: import original scss file, and override what you need.

Comment: thx! didn't recognise, that all values in bootstrap _variables.scss are defined as !default and that I can overwrite them before including bootstrap.scss to my project ;)